# How to cancel a chrome download before it starts and get the download url?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download, listener

I want to integrate my C# download manager using a Chrome Extension and I am new in extension development.

So I need to detect when a download request is sent in chrome. Then I need to get the url and pass it to my program to download. I tried it but couldn't get any response.

My code:

**manifest.js**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "ADM",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "downloads",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches" : ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js" : ["myscript.js"]
  }]
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (item) {
    chrome.downloads.cancel(item.id);
    alert(item.url);
});
```

As I said, this code didn't cancel the download and show the url for test. How can I do it?

Comment: I forgot to change `content_script` js filename, sorry for that. It must be `myscript.js`. Except this mistake, I tried it using a simple alert function and the script runs when a url is matched with regex.

Comment: You still need an event page. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch

Comment: As I understand, I need to use `sendMessage` and `onMessage` to do it. Is it true?

Comment: Unless you need to actually modify the page contents, you dont need a content script. Just put your download redirect code in the event page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access privileged Chrome apis from a content script, which is not permitted for security reasons. You need to move your code to an event page.

```
"background": { "scripts": ["myscript.js"], "persistent": false }
```

Also, read the architecture overview: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch